# ReactNative app is successfully installed but it's not started from WebStorm

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to build ReactNative app for my devices I get this:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 25.191 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Starting the app (adb shell am start -n com.neborofeed/com.neborofeed.MainActivity.../bin/sh: adb: command not found
```

The app is installed on my device, but it's not started automatically. When I copy this command to the terminal `adb shell am start -n com.neborofeed/com.neborofeed.MainActivity`, the app is started as expected.

Comment: How/where are you triggering the build? Is it in an IDE? Or in the same shell that successfully runs the `adb` command?

Comment: Hi, Am also trying to set up WebStorm, did you find any solution for this? What is your run configuration?, Care to add the configuration which you are running on? All i get is Loading dependency graph. nothing is building for me. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It's seems that the script is not able to find adb, have you added the PATH in your `~/.bash_profile` or similar?

If you have not try running:

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If you have your sdk in a different directory, then update the path in the command above.

Comment: I suggest that you keep trying along these lines, @SemyonTikhonenko. `/bin/sh: adb: command not found` quite clearly is indicating that the adb tool is not in your login shell's path. You need to find where your platform-tools directory is and you need to find where your path is being set and you need to add the directory to your path.

Comment: I added platfrom-tools into $PATH variable. So when I type adb in terminal the command is found successfully. And when I copy the command into terminal directory it works. And I tried you suggestion. My platform-tools are here /Users/Mac/Library/Android/sdk/platform-toolsfor sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this one then work for me after restart MAC
Noted: Don't forget to restart your MAC

[image]